# NSUrlRequest Not Working Objective C

Tags: objective-c, nsurlrequest

I am trying to use the code below to 'trigger' the web address. The web server doesn't return any data. But the NSURLConnection is being established.

```
NSString *serverAddressTest = @"http://domain.com";
NSString *fullWebAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?CustomerName=%@&ContactNo=%@&Products=%@",serverAddressTest,customer,contactnumber,allProductsInString];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullWebAddress];
NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
if (theConnection) {
    NSMutableData *webData = [NSMutableData data];
    NSLog(@"%@",webData);
}
else {
    NSMutableData *webData = [NSMutableData data];
    NSLog(@"%@",webData);
}
```

Comment: Most probably you should encode the url

Comment: Does the error delegate method get called?

Comment: No errors, in debug it hits the

    if (theConnection) {
        NSMutableData *webData = [NSMutableData data];
        NSLog(@"%@",webData);
     }

Comment: Nslog fullWebAddress. To see if it is what it should be.

Comment: fullWebAddress is the correct web address

Answer (score 0):

When you write:

```
NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest
                                                               delegate:self];
```

you are starting an asynchronous url connection.

Then immediately after that you are testing whether the connection was successful or not and creating an instance of `NSMutableData` with *local* scope.  Your `NSURLConnectionDelegate` methods (which you haven't posted) will not have access to this locally-scoped `NSMutableData` variable.

Have you indeed implemented the methods of the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` protocol?

Answer (score 0):

Try to send synchronous request to localise the problem:

```
NSError *error;
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: theRequest
                                           returningResponse: nil
                                                       error: &error];

NSLog(@"error = %@, \ndata = %@", error, returnData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to also implement the delegate Protocols. ( As NSBum says)

Using Apples [example](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html)
shown here is the data is returned when the parts are put together.:

```
    NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com/"]
                                              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                          timeoutInterval:60.0];

    // Create the NSMutableData to hold the received data.
    // receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
 receivedData = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity: 0];

    // create the connection with the request
    // and start loading the data
    NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    if (!theConnection) {
        // Release the receivedData object.
        receivedData = nil;
            NSLog(@"FAIL " );
        // Inform the user that the connection failed.
    }



}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{

     NSLog(@" response %@", response);

    // This method is called when the server has determined that it
    // has enough information to create the NSURLResponse object.

    // It can be called multiple times, for example in the case of a
    // redirect, so each time we reset the data.

    // receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
    [receivedData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    // Append the new data to receivedData.
    // receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
    [receivedData appendData:data];

     NSLog(@" receivedData %@", receivedData);
}
```

receivedData is not local but declared elsewhere. (NSMutableData*  receivedData;)

I do not use this much so cannot expand further without reading the docs fully myself; which is what you need to do. :-)